# list view in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

```
String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_icc, R.id.label, adobe_products));
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

I have been trying this in fragment with the following edited code

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icc, parent, false);
ListView list = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_icc, R.id.label, adobe_products);
list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
list.setClickable(true);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

There is an error in setAdapter statement

Comment: What is the question? Good reading: [ask], [mcve]. Try to keep "plz" and "hlp" and "!!!" to texting with your buddies and use real words here

Comment: So, there's an "error in setAdapter statement"  Perhaps it would help us help you to know what the error is.

Comment: You should use RecyclerView instead of ListView according to documentation https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 2):

> ListView list = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Replace with

> ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Hope it fixes your problem